# private and public web service authentication for php web service

Tags: web-services, apache, authentication

I have two web services(ie my_public_api and my_private_api) running in server1. (PHP,Apache)

http:// ipaddress/my_public_api -- Can be accessed by everyone.

http:// ipaddress/otherfuncation/my_private_api  - should be accessed only by approved user or specific ipaddress(server2)

I would like to implement some authentication for this. Can this be done using htpasswd basic authentication? if not what could be possible way to implement this.
In case if I use client authentication, is that possible only to protect my private_api and let the my_public_api accessble to everyone.

Comment: What are the purposes of the two API? Does one insert and pull data from databases while the returns unsensitive information?

Comment: Yes, The my_public_api will receive data(mainly from mobile app) and will be stored in a table for some purpose. So it will not impact any of my other tables. But it case of my_private_api it will be called from some other server and do some sensitive action and return the data. So I need secure only my_private_api　 and grant permission to only specific person/ipaddress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a way to accomplish this using SSL,

1. Generate Server and Client Certificates
2. Point the generated certificate on the apache.
3. Restrict api location / virtual path in the httpd.conf
4. Distribute the client certificate to whom you want to grant the access.

check [here](http://www.garex.net/apache/) to know how to set up SSL certificates

eg: httpd.conf

```
<Location /mysite/private_api>
SSLRequireSSL
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 1
</Location>
```

Check [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_howto.html#arbitraryclients) for more details